# One to many SQL query with diagonal results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have three tables. It's in the housing industry. So I have a Unit table, an Amenities table, and a UserDefined table.

For each one entry in the unit table, I want to display all the amenities, and userdefined values in one row.

```
UnitID   |   UnitName
---------|---------------
  1      |   123 Main St
  2      |   456 Fake Rd
  3      |   789 Madeup Blvd
```

Amenities Table

```
UnitID   |   Amenity Desc
---------|-----------------
  1      |    Has Pool
  1      |    Has Parking
  1      |    Includes Electric
  2      |    Has Parking
  2      |    Large Closets
```

User Defined Table

```
UnitID   |   UDF Desc
---------|------------------
  1      |    Property MGR
  1      |    Show Online
  2      |    Property MGR
  2      |    Don't Show Online
```

What I need to display is

```
UnitID   |   Name           |    Pool   |   Park     |    UDF1    |    UDF2   ...And so on
---------|------------------|-----------|------------|------------|-------------
  1      |  123 Main St     | Has Pool  | Incl Prkg  |   Prp MGR  |  ShowOnline
  2      |  456 Fake Rd     |           | Incl Prkg  |   Prp MGR  |  Don't Online
```

The problem is that when I run my query it comes out like this:

```
UnitID   |   Name           |    Pool   |   Park     |    UDF1    |    UDF2   ...And so on
---------|------------------|-----------|------------|------------|-------------
  1      |  123 Main St     |           |            |            |  ShowOnline
  1      |  123 Main St     |           |            |   Prp MGR  |  
  1      |  123 Main St     |           | Incl Prkg  |            |
  1      |  123 Main St     | Has Pool  |            |            |
  2      |  456 Fake Rd     |           |            |            |  Don't Online
  2      |  456 Fake Rd     |           |            |   Prp MGR  |  
  2      |  456 Fake Rd     |           | Incl Prkg  |            |
```

I'm sure people have seen this before, and so I'm curious what it takes to do this right. What piece am I missing.

Here's the query as I have it now, if that helps:
FYI, I've also tried running it with the DISTINCT parameter.

```
SELECT units.propid, 
       units.name, 
       units.street1, 
       units.city, 
       units.state, 
       units.zip, 
       units.sqft, 
       units.bedrooms, 
       units.bathrooms, 
       unittypes.unittype, 
       "" 
       AS AMENITIESS, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 1, true, false) 
       AS Fireplace, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 2, true, false) 
       AS Carpet, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 3, true, false) 
       AS Hardwood, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 4, true, false) 
       AS Dishwasher, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 5, true, false) 
       AS Furnished, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 6, true, false) 
       AS [Electricity Included], 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 7, true, false) 
       AS [Trash Included], 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 8, true, false) 
       AS [Has A/C], 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 9, true, false) 
       AS [Deck;Patio; or Porch], 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 10, true, false) 
       AS [Laundry in Unit], 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 3, true, false) 
       AS [Laundry on site], 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 12, true, false) 
       AS [Has Storage], 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 13, true, false) 
       AS [Has Garage], 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 14, true, false) 
       AS [Parking Included], 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 15, true, false) 
       AS 
       [Parking Available for a Fee], 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 16, true, false) 
       AS OnBusRoute, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 17, true, false) 
       AS BreakfastBar, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 18, true, false) 
       AS Microwave, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 19, true, false) 
       AS UndergroundParking, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 20, true, false) 
       AS HeatIncluded, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 21, true, false) 
       AS FencedInYard, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 22, true, false) 
       AS StainlessAppliances, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 23, true, false) 
       AS HasPool, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 30, true, false) 
       AS Patio, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 31, true, false) 
       AS Deck, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 32, true, false) 
       AS Porch, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 33, true, false) 
       AS FitnessCenter, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 34, true, false) 
       AS CommunityRoom, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 35, true, false) 
       AS Elevator, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 36, true, false) 
       AS Vending, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 37, true, false) 
       AS WhirlpoolTub, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 38, true, false) 
       AS CentralAir, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 39, true, false) 
       AS VaultedCeilings, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 40, true, false) 
       AS GasFireplace, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 41, true, false) 
       AS WoodburningFireplace, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 42, true, false) 
       AS DecorativeFireplace, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 43, true, false) 
       AS PrivateEntrance, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 44, true, false) 
       AS OnSiteOffice, 
       Iif([unitamenities].[amenityid] = 45, true, false) 
       AS CableInternetIncluded, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 1, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") AS Beds, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 2, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") AS Baths, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 3, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") AS DenLoft, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 4, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") AS Description, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 5, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") AS WebID, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 7, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") AS Location, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 18, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS FurnitureAvailable, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 21, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS Landlord, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 22, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS LaundryDetails, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 23, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS LaundryAmt, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 24, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS ParkingDetails, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 29, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS Pets, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 33, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS Schools, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 47, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS Utilities, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 57, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS Latitude, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 58, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS Longitude, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 59, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS PicSm, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 60, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS PicLg, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 61, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS Floorplan, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 62, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS IsSmokeFree, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 77, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS Manager, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 71, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS AvailNow, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 72, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS AvailAug, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 73, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS AvailShortTerm, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 74, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS AvailSublet, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 75, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS AvailFrom, 
       Iif([unituserdefinedvalues].[userdefinedid] = 76, 
       [unituserdefinedvalues].[value], "") 
       AS AvailTo 
FROM   ((units 
         INNER JOIN unitamenities 
                 ON units.unitid = unitamenities.unitid) 
        INNER JOIN unittypes 
                ON units.unittypeid = unittypes.unittypeid) 
       INNER JOIN unituserdefinedvalues 
               ON units.unitid = unituserdefinedvalues.unitid;
```

Comment: Ha ha. Very funny. Also this is M$SQL, right?

Comment: Have you not considered storing things like `Pool` and `Park` as `BOOL` variables inside the `Unit` table? Why are you doing so much work in the SQL table that should be done in the application layer? This is a very impractical approach. If you need to have multiple Amenities that may expand in the future, try having a `Unit` table, a `Label` table, and a `Value` table.

Comment: This is M$SQL, but I would gladly welcome MySQL. I'm pulling the data from a read-only MySQL database, creating the query views in Access, and then copy and pasting them to my web code.

Comment: As for using booleans and stuff, it is all designed right with booleans and different values, but I have read-only access so I can't create new tables or change the data types which they are stored as. I just put it the way I did so it would be easy to read and understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a lot of work for yourself.

Try a `Labels` table like this (which would include user-defined values):

```
LabelID  |   AmenityDesc
---------|-----------------
  1      |    Pool
  2      |    Parking
  3      |    Includes Electric
  4      |    Has Parking
  5      |    Show Online
```

and an `Options` table:

```
UnitID   |  LabelID |  OptionValue
---------|-------------------------
  1      |    1     |  1
  1      |    2     |  1
  1      |    3     |  1
  1      |    4     |  1
  1      |    5     |  1
  2      |    2     |  1
  2      |    5     |  0
```

and so on and so forth then join it all together with a query

As per your edit, here's a way to solve things in the application layer (pseudocode):

```
$results := sql('SELECT * FROM Amenities WHERE UnitID = ?');
$unit[?]['amenities'] := array();
foreach ($results as $result):
    $unit[?]['amenities'][] = $result['AmenityDesc'];
endfor
```

To check if a unit has some amenity:

```
if ('amenity' is in $unit[?]['amenities']):
    // do stuff
endif
```

Comment: Problem is that I'm accessing a third party read only database. So I can't create extra queries, or new tables. I have to create one single query to pull all the data using one Select statement. Otherwise I would just create a few queries and then combine them.

Comment: See my edit, there's one way to go about it. I would really avoid using big SQL queries or else you will face a nightmare if anything changes in the future

Comment: So if I get you right then you're saying:
-I should loop over each table separately, inserting them all into some kind of array or structure?
IE
foreach ($item1 in $unittable){
  foreach ($item2 in $amenitiesTable){
   //Add items to array
  }
  foreach ($item3 in $UDFtable){
   //Add Items to array
  }
}

Then by the end I should have a large array or structure which has all the info I need, one row at a time?

But this may be very time consuming for a website?!

Comment: Yes - if your hands are tied from the database you may be better off converting all of its contents into a usable and more flexible object instead.

Comment: Nevermind, I guess you understood what I meant. Just one thing though, with such large datasets won't that be very time consuming. Because I'm also pulling this from a database hosted in the cloud. So then every web request to my webpage will require the webserver to connect back out to the cloud with the SQL server. See where I'm going with this?

Comment: Your query so far is just as time-consuming if not worse. You're running something like ~80 if-statements per row. Maybe you should run a cronjob (say every 15 minutes) that will pull from those tables into your own usable format, then convert and store it on your own local SQL database.

Comment: That was sort of another idea I've been playing with. Ok. Thanks for your input. It definately helped me realize my options.